# Sorting an alphanumeric column in SQL with mix of alphanumeric and alpha-only values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, patindex

I have a requirement where I have to apply sort in an SQL query by an Alphanumeric column such that the values in it get sorted like the following:

```
AD
AH
AK1
B1
B2
B3x
B3y
B11
C1
C6
C12x
UIP
```

instead of the default way:

```
AD
AH
AK1
B1
B11
B2
B3x
B3y
C1
C12x
C6
UIP
```

I was able to write the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT [MyColumn]
FROM [MyTable]
ORDER BY
    LEFT([MyColumn], PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [MyColumn]) - 1),
    CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING([MyColumn], PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [MyColumn]), LEN([MyColumn]) - (PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE([MyColumn]))))),
    RIGHT([MyColumn], PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [MyColumn]) - 1)
```

I just need to know how to implement this in a conditional way such that this doesn't get triggered for alpha-only value else it would give error, or if there is a way to make it work with that as well?

P.S. The environment is SQL Server 2014.

Comment: This is almost always a sign of normalization misses. When you have to resort to string manipulation in the order by it is usually because the data contains two (or more) values in a single tuple. This violates 1NF and causes all sort of anguish.

Comment: Out of interest, could you also, have data that perhaps looks like `'B3y2'` and `'B3y11'`? If so, which should be ordered first? *Edit: Also, if the answer is yes, how many levels could you therefore get to? Could you end up with a record with the value `'B3y11A3d12AS4'`?*

Comment: @SeanLange yes I agree to that, neither the database nor the data is in my control here. The requirement was presented such that all columns returned by a particular stored procedure should be sort-able and in case of this particular column they were not happy with the default way a string gets sorted.

Comment: @Larnu it doesn't seem at the moment that the data may have that structure yet, but I may have take that into consideration i guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit of a mess to look at and I agree with Sean Lange that you should look into recording this in more than one field, but you can use `case` expressions within your `order by` to have conditional ordering:

```
declare @t table(c nvarchar(10));
insert into @t values('AD'),('AH'),('AK1'),('B1'),('B2'),('B3x'),('B3y'),('B11'),('C1'),('C6'),('C12x'),('UIP');

select c
from @t
order by
      case when patindex('%[0-9]%', c) = 0
           then c
           else left(c, patindex('%[0-9]%', c) - 1)
      end
      ,case when patindex('%[0-9]%', c) = 0
           then 0
           else convert(int,substring(c,patindex('%[0-9]%', c),len(c) - (patindex('%[0-9]%', reverse(c)))))
      end
      ,right(c,case when patindex('%[0-9]%', c) = 0
                   then 0
                   else patindex('%[0-9]%', c) - 1
               end
      );
```

Output:

```
+------+
|  c   |
+------+
| AD   |
| AH   |
| AK1  |
| B1   |
| B2   |
| B3x  |
| B3y  |
| B11  |
| C1   |
| C6   |
| C12x |
| UIP  |
+------+
```

Comment: This is almost about it for the given string formats, although there are two problems, 1 being the chunk has a -1 in the end that will most likely result in an error, and 2 being minor issue with having 'UIP' come as 3rd instead of the last item in result. But this is almost the answer required. I will make the edit in your answer to work with this.

Comment: @MusabM.Jafri This is important information that should have been included in your question.  You will note how my results match the required output in your question.

Comment: I copied and executed your script brother and it didn't result in UIP being at the right spot, that is what I commented. Along with the -1 at the end of your code also giving an error. Both points have no related to the question it self.